# How to usr use the observe method on the model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to register observers on my models. But I don't want to register observers in the boot method of one of your service providers, because it may cost much. I want to register the observer only when I use the model

In document https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers:

To register an observer, use the observe method on the model you wish to observe. You may register observers in the boot method of one of your service providers. In this example, we'll register the observer in the AppServiceProvider:

There is only example using AppServiceProvider.

In api document https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_observe, there are methods `observe` and `registerObserver`. How can I use it?

Answer (score 3):

Just add this into your Model class:

```php
/**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::observe('Your\Observer\Namespace');
    }
```

It will automatically setup the observer the 1st time the model is used (unlike service provider which setups it every time).

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `ObserverServiceProvider` in `App\Providers` and add it to the `providers` array in `config/app.php`.

`observe()` and `registerObserver()` are methods you call in `the boot()` method of your ServiceProvider.

```
class ObserverServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // Multiple observers
        MyModel::observe([new ModelAObserver(), new ModelBObserver()]);

        // Single observer
        MyModel::registerObserver(new ModelCObserver());
    }
}
```

To trigger specific observer types in your model, add a static boot method to your model:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::saved(function ($model) {
        dd($model);
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and registering in AppServiceProvider

Comment: I want to register the observer only when I use the model